# firebase storage ref is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, webpack, firebase-storage

Im new in web development . i tried to find an answer all over the internet in the past 24 hours without success and now im reaching out here

this is my err :

**Uncaught TypeError: *firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3*_.storage.ref is not a function**

this is the firebase.js file :

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';


const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: ""
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const storage = getStorage(app);
```

and im importing the storage in the component like that :

```
import {storage} from "../../firebase";
```

this is the upload func :

```
    const upload = (items) => {
    items.forEach((item) => {
        const fileName = new Date().getTime() + item.label + item.file.name;
        const uploadTask = storage.ref(`/items/${fileName}`).put(item.file);
        uploadTask.on(
            "state_changed",
            (snapshot) => {
                const progress =
                    (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                console.log("Upload is " + progress + "% done");
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            },
            () => {
                uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
                    setMovie((prev) => {
                        return { ...prev, [item.label]: url };
                    });
                    setUploaded((prev) => prev + 1);
                });
            }
        );
    });
};
```

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

You are using the syntax for the legacy namespaced Firebase JS SDK (v8 and older) with the newer modular Firebase SDK (v9 and newer).

Instead of `storage.ref()`, you need to be using [`ref(storage, path)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage.md#ref):

```js
import { storage } from "../../firebase"
import { ref, uploadBytes } from "firebase/storage";

const upload = (items) => {
  items.forEach((item, index) => {
    const storageRef = ref(storage, `/items/${fileName}`);
    const uploadTask = uploadBytes(storageRef, item.file);

    uploadTask.on(
      "state_changed",
      (snapshot) => {
        const progress =
          Math.round((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 1000)/10;
        console.log(`Upload #${index+1} is ${progress}% done`);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => {
        console.log(`Upload #${index+1} is complete, fetching URL...`);
        getDownloadURL(storageRef)
          .then((url) => {
            console.log(`Upload #${index+1} is now available at ${url}.`);
            setMovie((prev) => {
              return { ...prev, [item.label]: url };
            });
            setUploaded((prev) => prev + 1);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      }
    );
  });
}
```

I encourage you to read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/create-reference#web-version-9) completely and read the [migration guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) so that you can see which SDK version the code you are working off of was built for.

**Note:** You should further improve this code to handle errors better, such as set an error message visible to the user for failed uploads.

Comment: Hi sam , I appreciate your comment , i will read more the documentation . thank you for the tip i hope to success with this function . i wish all the best and have a great day